# Three.js - Buffer geometry particles, need to animate random groups of particles in system

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a `PointCloud` with a large number ( 200K+ ) of particles. This `PointCloud` is constructed using `THREE.BufferGeometry`, with each vertices position set using `Float32Array( numParticles * 3 )`.

I would like to animate the `x,y` positions of randomly selected clusters of particles every `n` number of seconds. This process needs to be as efficient as possible — so looping though all the particles in the `update()` and selecting random clusters to animate, is too computationally expensive.

Is there a better way to achieve something like this in `Three.js` ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410761/how-to-quickly-update-a-large-buffergeometry

Comment: @WestLangley Brillant, I didn't find that questions. Thanks!

Comment: @WestLangley, ( I know this should probably be another question, but..) I have that setup, but where do I access the vertices positions, before it was `geometry.attributes.position.array` - do I just use `geometry.attributes.position.array.subarray` ?

Comment: I have not tried this, actually. I was just trying to point you in the right direction... Also see http://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/5042. If you can figure it out and post your own answer, that would be great!

Comment: it would also probably be worth looking into moving more of the logic into the shaders. You could have some random index define the groups, do some tests etc.

Comment: @pailhead I've thought about that - but I'm definitely not a `WebGL` expert. I've implement the solution that @WestLangley has suggested and it seems to be pretty effective so far.

Comment: Oh. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538901/tweening-particles-in-buffergeometry/27539193#27539193)