# THREE JS computeVertexNormals() performance

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a large buffer geometry, around 4 million vertexes, that needs to have a small area of shading updated.  I currently randomly update the vertexNormals, but it causes a lag.  I have tried using the updateRange.offset of the geometry([How to quickly update a large BufferGeometry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410761/how-to-quickly-update-a-large-buffergeometry/20422336#20422336))
 but looking into the source code i dont think this effects the vertexNormals() function.

loop me 1,000 times:

```
GRID.geometry.attributes.position.array[ (array_position + 2)  ] = _position[2] -  WEBGLzTranslate ; 
GRID.geometry.attributes.color.array[ (array_position) + 0 ] = color.r;
GRID.geometry.attributes.color.array[ (array_position) + 1 ] = color.g;
GRID.geometry.attributes.color.array[ (array_position) + 2 ] = color.b;
```

then set update:

```
if(minArrayPosition < Infinity){
    GRID.geometry.attributes.position.updateRange = {};
    GRID.geometry.attributes.position.offset = minArrayPosition;
    GRID.geometry.attributes.position.count = maxArrayPosition - minArrayPosition;
    GRID.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
    GRID.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
}

GRID.geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;
GRID.material.needsUpdate = true;
if(Math.random() > .99)
{
    GRID.geometry.computeFaceNormals(); 
    GRID.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    console.log('Updating Shadding');
}
```

Ideally i would like to have the range work for the vertexNormals, i think.  maybe somewhere in here(BufferGeometry.js:657):

```
if ( attributes.position ) {

        var positions = attributes.position.array;

        if ( attributes.normal === undefined ) {

            this.addAttribute( 'normal', new BufferAttribute( new Float32Array( positions.length ), 3 ) );

        } else {

            // reset existing normals to zero

            var array = attributes.normal.array;

            for ( var i = 0, il = array.length; i < il; i ++ ) {

                array[ i ] = 0;

            }

        }

        var normals = attributes.normal.array;

        var vA, vB, vC,

        pA = new Vector3(),
        pB = new Vector3(),
        pC = new Vector3(),

        cb = new Vector3(),
        ab = new Vector3();

        // indexed elements

        if ( index ) {

            var indices = index.array;

            if ( groups.length === 0 ) {

                this.addGroup( 0, indices.length );

            }

            for ( var j = 0, jl = groups.length; j < jl; ++ j ) {

                var group = groups[ j ];

                var start = group.start;
                var count = group.count;

                for ( var i = start, il = start + count; i < il; i += 3 ) {

                    vA = indices[ i + 0 ] * 3;
                    vB = indices[ i + 1 ] * 3;
                    vC = indices[ i + 2 ] * 3;

                    pA.fromArray( positions, vA );
                    pB.fromArray( positions, vB );
                    pC.fromArray( positions, vC );

                    cb.subVectors( pC, pB );
                    ab.subVectors( pA, pB );
                    cb.cross( ab );

                    normals[ vA ] += cb.x;
                    normals[ vA + 1 ] += cb.y;
                    normals[ vA + 2 ] += cb.z;

                    normals[ vB ] += cb.x;
                    normals[ vB + 1 ] += cb.y;
                    normals[ vB + 2 ] += cb.z;

                    normals[ vC ] += cb.x;
                    normals[ vC + 1 ] += cb.y;
                    normals[ vC + 2 ] += cb.z;

                }

            }
```

Should i be looking into morphing materials instead??  Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to write your own implementation of `computeVertexNormals()` which does follow the limits you set. The freezing is because JavaScript can't execute anything else until the current function completes its processing or waits for an event. A long compute loop will "freeze" the browser for its entire duration.

Comment: maybe try to run computeVertexNormals asynch in a set interval function that kills itself after running once?  i then could space it out but atleast wouldnt see the lag as much?  Ill submit computeVertexNormals({offset:Int,range:int}) to Git as feature request

Answer (score 0):

BufferGeometry already supports updating a sub-range of an attribute -- that includes the normal.

BufferGeometry.computeVertexNormals() supports both indexed and non-indexed geometries. Indexed geometries support shared vertices, so there may be faces outside your index range that must be included in the calculation to achieve proper results.

- west langley
  https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9574